# Start or Stop windows services using a bat file

Tags: file, batch-file

I need to start or stop around 5 windows services using a .bat file. I have been doing the below. But once i run this, i get an error- %x service not found.

```
for %%x in (
"service 1"
"service 2"
"service 3"
) do net start | find %%x > nul 2>&1 
if not .%errorlevel%.==.0. net start %%x >nul
goto skip

:skip
pause
```

Comment: can someone help me here?

Comment: You could also use the `SC QUERY` command to check `STATE` of the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%x in (
"service 1"
"service 2"
"service 3"
) do (
 net start | find %%x > nul 2>&1 
 if errorlevel 1 net start %%x >nul
 if errorlevel 1 goto skip
)

:skip
```

In your code, only the first `net start` will be executed in the `for` loop. You need to form the commands into a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of lines).

The downside is that when a `code block` is parsed , *any* `%var%` will be replaced by the value of `%var%` *at that time*.

Consequently, you need to use the original syntax for `errorlevel`,`if errorlevel n` which means "if errorlevel is n **or greater than n**"

Since you appear to want to retry, then the instruction to be executed in the case of `errorlevel = 1 or more` after the `net start` is to retry, and I've assumed you want to go to `skip` if that retry fails. Note that if the original attempt succeeds, `errorlevel` will be `0` (I assume) hence the `if` will fail and *not* execute the retry and thus `errorlevel` will remain at `0`.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer. In your code, errorlevel 1 means the service is started so asking it to skip?

Comment: @Magoo the second `net start` is not a retry. It's the first time it actually starts the service, the previous `net start` being simply a query to check if the service was already running.

Comment: @Mounika the second `if errorlevel 1` means there was an error starting the service, so it exits the loop.

Comment: I don't know what value `net start` assigns to `errorlevel` when it fails. Usually, `0` is assigned for success and non-zero for failure, so the instruction `if errorlevel 1 dothis` will execute `dothis` if `errorlevel` is not 0 (1 or greater) so therefore if the `net start` fails, *assuming* that `net start` will set `errorlevel` to `0` on success and `non-0` on fail. Hence the first will attempt a retry and the second will exit to `skip` if the retry also fails

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: I'd missed the first `net start` being a query